# I overloaded operator > but it still says no operator matches operands

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I need B class to have a min priority queue of AToTime objects.

AToTime have `operator>`, and yet I receive error telling me than there is no operator> matching the operands...

```
#include <queue>
#include <functional>

using namespace std; 

class B
{
  public:
    B();
    virtual ~B();
  private:
    log4cxx::LoggerPtr m_logger;
    class AToTime 
    {
    public:
      AToTime(const ACE_Time_Value& time, const APtr a) : m_time(time), m_a(a){}

      bool operator >(const AToTime& other)
      {
        return m_time > other.m_time;
      }

    public:
      ACE_Time_Value m_time;
      APtr           m_a;
    };

    priority_queue<AToTime, vector<AToTime>, greater<AToTime> > m_myMinHeap;
};
```

Comment: As a general comment, when posting a question, try to reduce the space that the code takes (trying to fit as much code as possible) while maintaining readability. Try reducing your problem by removing code that are unrelated to the problem (the logger definition) useless comments (`// private members` just before `private` does not offer anything) and compact them `public: // no point using private members here` if they add information. The same goes with free extra space (two empty lines before the `priority_queue` definition)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
    bool operator >(const AToTime& other)
```

It should be a const function.

```
    bool operator >(const AToTime& other) const
```

Answer (score 1):

[Kenny's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2441705/what-am-i-doing-wrong/2441710#2441710) already shows you how to make this work.

Note that I would prefer to implement binary operators which treat their operands equally (they're not modifying them) as free functions:

```
inline bool operator>(const AToTime& khs, const AToTime& rhs)
{
  return lhs.m_time > rhs.m_time;
}
```

Further, usually users expect all relational operators to be present if one of them is there. Since the std library mostly wants `operator<`, except for equality I'd implement the others on top of `operator<`:

```
inline bool operator<(const AToTime& khs, const AToTime& rhs)
{return lhs.m_time < rhs.m_time;}

inline bool operator>(const AToTime& khs, const AToTime& rhs)
{return rhs < lhs;}

inline bool operator<=(const AToTime& khs, const AToTime& rhs)
{return !(lhs > rhs);}

inline bool operator>=(const AToTime& khs, const AToTime& rhs)
{return !(lhs < rhs);}

inline bool operator==(const AToTime& khs, const AToTime& rhs)
{return lhs.m_time == rhs.m_time;}

inline bool operator!=(const AToTime& khs, const AToTime& rhs)
{return !(lhs.m_time == rhs.m_time);}
```

Comment: You dont need to define these manually. They are defined in utility. You just need to include them and use them. "using namespace std::rel_ops;" http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/utility/rel_ops/

Comment: @Martin: A potential problem with those is that you get them for all the types in your namespace. I haven't seen them used in the wild and haven't used them myself either. Are they used? (Maybe that would make a good CW question?)